# How to set a conditional boolean for tasks in an SSIS package?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, boolean, ssis-2012

I have a flow of tasks that I want to be run, but only IF a variable (I assume boolean) is set to "True". Basically I want a variable that can be functionally turned on/off.

Sometimes I will want the flow of tasks to execute and send emails to a client. Sometimes I will want that functionality turned off. I understand the "off/on" will be done manually, I just want to save the time of going and disabling multiple tasks. Figured it would be streamlined if I can quickly have all the tasks in the control flow reference an On/Off boolean of sorts.

Please let me know if you need more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each connection on the control flow can have an expression with true false result.

Set a variable (or a parameter) to do that.

[image]